# Bit manipulation: compute sum over all bits (aka number of 1's) in a uint64_t

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

In C++, I would like to compute the number of bits that is 1 in a `uint64_t`

```
# A few examples in uint8_t:
0b00000000  ==> 0
0b01000001  ==> 2
0b00110101  ==> 4
0b11111111  ==> 8
```

I need to perform a lot  (say millions) of such operations, is there a fast way to do so (maybe with some pre-processing)?

One possibility I can think of is to create a lookup table for every `N` bit (say `N=8`), and perform `64/N` lookups for a `uint64_t`. Is there a better solution for this? If I decide to go for the above approach, how should I set `N`? (To my understanding even ignoring all pre-processing computation, it is not the case that the larger `N` is, the better, Because the look-up speed actually depends on whether the look-up table can fit in cache?)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is the [Hamming Weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) algorithm.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer

Comment: I'm not sure how it compares in performance, but `std::bitset<64>{bits}.count()` is really simple.

Comment: This has been asked dozens of times.

Comment: http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/pop.c.txt You can call this on both half the 64-bit and add them together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way is [`__builtin_popcountll`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) on GCC and Clang and [`_mm_popcnt_u64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531475.aspx) for VC++. 
When compiled with appropriate flags (e.g. `-march=native`), this should yield optimal performance as the intrinsic is reduced to the assembler instruction [POPCNT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT) that was introduced together with SSE 4.2. [**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5648a6354a7bb716).

And if that's not applicable try a [Bit twiddling Hack](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetTable) using lookup tables.

Answer (score 2):

There's the `popcnt` (population count) instruction which is very likely the fastest way to get the number of 1 bits.
Note that your processor must support SSE4.2.
You can use both intrinsics and builtin function, but I suggest intrinsics function because they're supported by all major compilers:

```
#include "nmmintrin.h"
auto bitsOn = _mm_popcnt_u64(10);
```